# Does binutils-gold has support for arm/Android?

Tags: android, linux, ld, binutils, gold-linker

I am trying to replace my default `arm-eabi-ld` with installed from `binutils-gold` `ld`, however during linking I have got

```
(..../*.o) requires unsupported dynamic reloc; recompile with -fPIC
```

`LOCAL_CFLAGS := -fPIC` in Android.mk doesn't help very much. Is there any chance to use gold linker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

good news!

Latest version from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils/2.21.0.20110327-2ubuntu2/+buildjob/2436559 works for me!

my results:

linking with ld:    6 minutes

linking with gold:  **1 minute !!!!**

installation script:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils/2.21.0.20110327-2ubuntu2/+buildjob/2436559/+files/binutils_2.21.0.20110327-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils/2.21.0.20110327-2ubuntu2/+buildjob/2436559/+files/binutils-gold_2.21.0.20110327-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i binutils-gold_2.21.0.20110327-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb binutils_2.21.0.20110327-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

cd $ANDROID_NDK_DIR/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi/bin/
mv ld ld.backup
ln -s /usr/bin/ld.gold ld 

cd $ANDROID_NDK_DIR/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/
mv arm-eabi-ld arm-eabi-ld.backup
ln -s /usr/bin/ld.gold arm-eabi-ld
```

Comment: which version of android-ndk are you running ?

Comment: For Ubuntu 12.04 you can do sudo aptitude install binutils binutils-gold instead of downloading the .deb files